# NextJS sidebar like in official Docs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs) of NextJS has nice sidebar with style and function.

I wonder if we can access the source code of the sidebar of the official website, or taking a step back, any react/next package can support the [NextJS manifest file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/docs/manifest.json) so that we can learn from and reuse it?

Preferably it can work with the [next-mdx-remote](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote).

### So far I've got

- [opstrace/next-product-docs](https://github.com/opstrace/next-product-docs) has a [sidebar component](https://github.com/zentered/next-product-docs-example/blob/main/components/Sidebar.jsx) and is the most similar one to what I'm looking for, but the style is not as good.
- React components, they have good style but without no NextJS support (loading pages from manifest.json or file name).

  - [Stylish Sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylish-sidebar) (with hosted demo)
  - [React Multilevel Sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multilevel-sidebar) (with gif demo)
  - [@milon27/react-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@milon27/react-sidebar)
  - [next-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sidebar)
  - [react-pro-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar) from @Moein Moeinnia. This one is has an outstanding interactive UI.

TIA.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @Mel Yea, I used [nextra](https://nextra.vercel.app/).

Answer (score 1):

I have use a package called `react-pro-sidebar` and it's super cool.

Check it out

Comment: 'ProSidebarProvider' is deprecated.ts(6385)
ProSidebarProvider.d.ts(6, 4): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
(alias) const ProSidebarProvider: React.FC<ProSidebarProviderProps>
import ProSidebarProvider
@deprecated — ProSidebarProvider is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release.  => in next.js when its wrapping under _app.ts is it expexted behaviour